# Telegram webhook - Connection timed out

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Пробую настроить веб-хук api телеграма.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

[image: результат вывода getwebhookinfo]

Когда телеграм пытается отправить запрос на зарегистрированный (успешно) url,
[image: скриншот успешной регистрации вебхука]

получает "Connection timed out". Приводит в ступор тот факт, что если сделать тоже самое через postman, то ответ 200 и все работает.

SSL есть

[image: скриншот сертификата]

Может есть люди которые сталкивались с подобной проблемой. Помогите пожалуйста.

---

UPD: заметил кучу переходов на сайт. Для чего вы туда заходите?)

---

UPD 2: Грешу на хостинг. Использую Hostinger. Есть какой то способ проверить мою теорию? И какой хост будет лучше, в случае замены

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Скорее всего ваш код не успевает отработать за определённое время и сервер Телеграм сбрасывает подключение.

Comment: Как можно это проверить? Какую информацию надо добавить?
Если мой код не успевает отработать, то как тогда я смог добавить этот урл в вебхук?

Comment: Проверить, например профилируя код. Самое простое, например, писать в файл при достижении некоторых мест и измерять время исполнения.  При установке вебхука телеграм не делает запроса к обратному URL, только при дальнейших событиях.

Comment: Поясните что вы хотите профилировать. У меня там стоит заглушка, которая пишет в лог, если кто либо запросил страницу. 
Использую постман - пишет в лог. Пишу в чат телеграма, лог пустой, получаю последнее состояние веб хука "Connection timed out"